# AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension throws ImportModuleError on Lambda runtime 20

Tags: aws-lambda-extensions

Upgrade to latest AWS node runtime lts20, AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension throws error complain can't find aws-sdk module.

Updated AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension to the latest version: 11, still got same error.

`[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2024/01/29 01:57:18 INFO Serving on port 2773 2024-01-29T01:57:20.120Z   undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception   {     "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",     "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",     "stack": [         "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'",         "Require stack:",         "- /var/task/index.js",         "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",         "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",         "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",         "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",         "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"     ] }` 
Upgrade to latest AWS node runtime lts20, AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension throws error complain can't find aws-sdk module.

Expect AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extention works with latest node runtime.